# Control Mobile via pc using USB (No URL Control)

Tags: java, android, usb, controls, root

I want to control the mobile via pc using usb cable,

I found out lot many solution like ***Droid@Screen & AndroidScreenMonitor etc.,*** but this is an one way communication  am not able to control from PC.

But i have solutions to control mobile via URL ***webkey & vncdroid,droidscreen etc.,*** but it was slow.

So, i need to ***control mobile over usb***,Rooting is not a problem I am ready to root the mobile.

Please suggest the solution  either open source or Payable!!!

Comment: Did you try **"adb shell"** command?

Comment: how to display android screen in pc !!!

Comment: I think it is possible from kitkat and up versions only.

Comment: in kitkat screenshot option will be added!!!

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-media

Comment: ya screen recording available how to control you mobile using screen record!!?? that's what i am asking bro....

Comment: What do you mean by controlling ? do you want to use device as a emulator screen?

Comment: go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey if i click in pc it will reflect on mobile